# Trying to run an implementation of lsqcurvefit from the Optimization Toolbox from Matlab in python using curvefit

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to implement `lsqcurvefit` from matlab in Python using `curve_fit` with no success. Below is the matlab code I am trying to port to Python:

```matlab
myfun = @(x,xdata)(exp(x(1))./ xdata.^exp(x(2))) - x(3);
xstart = [4, -2, 54];
pX = [2, 3, 13, 12, 38, 39];
pY = [12.7595, 8.7857, -11.8802, -10.9528, -15.4390, -15.3083];

try
    fittedmodel = lsqcurvefit(myfun,xstart,double(pX),double(pY), [], [], optimset('Display', 'off'));
    disp("fitted model:");
    disp(fittedmodel);
catch
end
```

Below is my matlab output:

```
fitted model:
    4.8389    3.3577   -2.0000
```

Below is my Python code:

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

pX = [2, 3, 13, 12, 38, 39];
pY = [12.7595, 8.7857, -11.8802, -10.9528, -15.4390, -15.3083];

def myfun(x, xdata):
    temp_val_1 = np.exp(x[0])
    temp_val_2 = np.exp(x[1])
    temp_val_3 = x[2]
    temp_val_4 = np.power(xdata, temp_val_2)
    temp_val_5 = np.divide(temp_val_1, temp_val_4)
    temp_val_6 = temp_val_5 - temp_val_3
    return temp_val_6
        
popt, pcov = curve_fit(myfun, pX, pY, p0=([4, -2, 54]))
print(popt, "\n", pcov)
```

and below is my Python output:

```
myfun() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I understand that there is something wrong with the inputs, but I don't understand what to change to solve this and receive the same results as I do with matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few hints to get you started:

- Note that `curve_fit` expects a function with signature `f(xdata, *x)`, where `x` is your optimization variable, i.e. the searched coefficients. It's just the other way around compared to Matlab's `lsqcurvefit`. The notation `*x` is python specific and denotes a variable number of arguments.
- Additionally, you don't need to use the `np.power` and `np.divide` functions. The usual mathematical operators are overloaded for np.arrays and are applied elementwise. For example, this means that for two np.arrays `a / b` is equivalent to Matlab's `a ./ b`. Consequently, it's more convenient to write (and to read):

```py
def myfun(xdata, *x):
    return np.exp(x[0]) / xdata**np.exp(x[1]) - x[2]
```

I obtain the following coefficients:

```
[ 4.01234549 -0.47409326 21.70045585]
```

However, there seems to be an overflow for the term `np.exp(x[1])`, so it might be worth to reformulate the objective function or increase the floating point precision. i.e. use long doubles `dtype=np.float128`.